# Updating Python CLI while maintaining "python -c exectfile" interface

Tags: python, interface, command-line-interface, execfile

I have a number of scripts that reference a Python program via the:

`python -c "execfile('myfile.py'); readFunc(param='myParam', input='blahblah')"`

interface.  What I'd like to do is conceptually simple: Develop a more modular system with a "main" and a normal Python CLI interface that then calls these functions, but also MAINTAINS the existing interface, so the scripts built to use it still work.

Is this possible?

Ideally, if I was to call

```
python myFile readFunc myParam blabblah
```

It'd be something like:

```
main(sys.argv):
     readFunc(sys.argv[2], sys.arg[3])
```

I've tried something like that, but it hasn't quite worked.  Is it possible to keep both interfaces/methods of invocation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind stems from the optional arguments to the `execfile()` function.  You might be able to do something like this:

```
#!python
def main(args):
    results = do_stuff()
    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])

if __name__ == 'execfile':
    main(args)
```

... and then when you want to call it via `execfile()` you supply a dictionary for its optional `globals` argument:

```
#!sh
python -c 'execfile(myfile, {"__name__":"execfile", "args":(1,2,3)}); ...'
```

This does require a little extra work when you're calling your functionality via `-c` as you have to remember to pass that dictionary and over-ride `'__name__'` ... through I suppose you could actually use *any* valid Python identifier.  It's just that `__name__` is closest to what you're actually doing.

The next idea feels a little **dirty** but relies on the apparent handling of the `__file__` global identifier.  That seems to be unset when calling `python -c` and set if the file is being imported or executed.  So this works (at least for CPython 2.7.9):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
foo='foo'
if __name__ == '__main__' and '__file__' not in globals():
    print "Under -c:", foo

elif __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Executed standalone:", foo
```

... and if you use that please don't give me credit.  It looks ...

... ... ummm ....

... just ...

.... **WRONG**

Comment: I should note that the string "execfile" for `__name__` here is completely arbitrary and you might even be better using a string that can never collide with the name of any module into which your code might ever be imported.  Perhaps just '*' ... the literal asterisk string.

Comment: Yeah, the point is that the executing execfile interface needs to be persevered EXACTLY.  If we're going to change it, we might as well abandon it completely and bring things to the 21st century anyway.  I'll push for this, but there are a LOT of scripts build on that interface, so it would be best to do this in parallel right now.

Comment: You might do something with `__name__` == `'__main__'` and `'__file__'` not in globals().  I'm adding a sample to my posting.

Comment: I've accepted this answer, although I doubt it does exactly what I want it to do.  I appreciate the effort!

The good news is that I've been told we can abandon the old interface, so thankfully this isn't an issue anymore!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this one

```
python myFile readFunc myParam blabblah
```

correctly, you want to parse `argv[1]` as a command name to be executed.

So just do

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if len(sys.argv) < 2 or sys.argv[1].lower() == 'nop' or sys.argv[0] == '-c': # old, legacy interface
        pass
    elif sys.argv[1].lower() == 'readfunc': # new one
        readFunc(sys.argv[2:])
```

where the 2nd part gets executed on a direct execution of the file (either via `python file.py readFunc myParam blabblah` or via `python -m file readFunc myParam blabblah`)

The "nop" / empty `argv` branch comes to play when using the "legacy" interface: in this case, you most probably have given no cmdline arguments and thus can assume that you don't want to execute anything.

This makes the situation as before: the `readFunc` identifier is exported and can be used from within the `-c` script as before.